# How did they know about the ship/items in the badlands in another time-line?

Tags: plot-explanation, terra-nova

In the series *Terra Nova*:

The people from the year 2149 send a time capsule back in time. They never find the time capsule (Later named: '[The Probe](http://terranova.wikia.com/wiki/The_Probe)') that they send. 
So whatever they do in Terra Nova ('*in the past*') doesn't change the future because they are in some sort of different time-line if I remember correctly.

So my questions is about the ship/items that they are looking for in the badlands.

**Question:**
How did they know that the ship/items were there in the first place? How did the people from the future knew about those items and told Mira (& the six-ers) to search for them/gather them with the army at the last episodes.

Comment: everything will be explain in season 2.. Oh wait.. nevermind